# Authenticate with Google Drive API in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, go, google-drive-api

I created this web app completely in go-lang, which uses Google Drive API to authenticate users. Once user authenticated, it saves the token in a `<user-email>_token.json` file so the app can operate for 24 hours without the users involvement. It works fine. But now I want to separate the front-end from (Go-Lang)back-end and convert it to AngularJS.

So I have this problem with authentication. Because I should keep the authentication in server-side. But  then how would Angular know that the user is authenticated or not? Because I cannot use sessions.

Should I need to use JWT to this? If it is, then how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your token does not have to be on the server side.

Why? Because if you have many clients connected to your server, it would mean that all of these clients are sharing the same token and therefore have access to the Google Drive linked to this token. It does not make sense.

The token has to be on the client side. You should save the token as a cookie, maybe by using [JWT](https://jwt.io/), I let you read the documentation of JWT to know why it would be interesting to use it in your case or not.

Then on your Angular, you have to say something like "hey, this client has a cookie called "my-google-drive-token", let's check if that is a good one... Mmmmh, okay seems to be good, I display the Google Drive content".

Think about using good practices about security (using an encrypted token in your cookie, making the connection between the front and the back safe, [keep your API key safe](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en)...).

Your backend is only a gateway between your front-end and the Google Drive API.

Also, check the usefulness of your server. I think that in your case, a simple frontend connected to the Google API is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Actually `<user-email>_token.json` files will create for each user. Sorry I didn't mention in question. So in my app, users can add torrent magnets to download. And server will download it. Once the download finished It uploads to the users Gdrive. So the token has to be in server side right?

Comment: In your case yes. But I still think that is not the best solution.